# Im building a salesforce.com type of CRM - what is the right database architecture?

Tags: crm

I have developed a CRM for my company.   Next I would like to take that system and make it available for others to use in a hosted format.  Very much like a salesforce.com.  The question is what type of database structure would I use.  I see two options:

**Option 1. Each time a company signs up, I clone the master database for them.**

The disadvantage of this is that I could end up with thousands of databases.  Thats a lot of databases to backup every night.  My CRM uses cron jobs for maintanance, those jobs would have to run on all databases.

Each time I upgrade the system with a new feature, and need to add a new column to the database, I will have to add that column to thousands of databases.

**Option 2. Use only one database.**

At the beginning of EVERY table add "CompanyID".  In EVERY SQL statement add "and 
companyid={companyid}".

The advantage of this method is the simplicity of only one database.  Just one database to backup each night.  Just one database to update when needed.

The disadvantage is what if I get 1000 companies signing up, and each wants to store data on 100,000 leads, that 100,000,000 rows in the lead table, which worries me.

Does anyone know how the online hosted CRMs like salesforce.com do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you clone a table structure style to each new database id all sheets archived in master base indexed client clone is hash verified to access specific sheet run through a host machine at the front end of the master system. Then directing requests as primary role. Internal access is batched to read/write slave systems in groups. Obviously set raid configurations to copy real time and scheduled. Balance requests for load to speed of system resources. That way you separated the security flawed from ui and connection to the retention schema. it seems like simplified structures and reducing policy requests cut down request rss in the query processing. or  Simply a man in the middle approach from inside out.

Answer (score -3):

1) Splitting your data into smaller groups in a safe, unthinking way (such as one database per grouping) is almost always best if you want to scale. In this case, unless for some reason you want to query between companies, keeping them in separate databases is best.

2) If you are updating all of the databases by hand, you are doing something wrong if you want to scale. You'd want to automate the process.

3) Ultimately, salesforce.com uses this as the basis of their DB infrastructure:
http://blog.database.com/blog/2011/08/30/database-com-is-open-for-business/

Comment: I disagree with using a different database for every company. Imagine if you had 10,000 companies sign up? Each database has at least one user account associated with it. Following the principle of least privilege each user should be granted only the permissions they need so they should not be able to drop a table or delete a database if that is not required of them. Imagine having 10,000 different databases, each with only one or two tables - tables that are the same for all 10,000 databases. Related data should be stored in the same database. You can analyze it better this way

Comment: I've seen people go your route and it has many, many flaws that resulted in their engineers basically saying "Yes, we cannot fix this without redeveloping our sharding model." That company was one of Salesforce's major competitors. They've since migrated.

Comment: It is far, far, far easier to migrate individual customer accounts [on the scale of 50GB+ of data in a database per customer] as a database than it is to design a sharding scheme for a single database that is fast, efficient, and requires a minimum of engineering time. At 20 customers, you've already filled up a 1TB SSD on 3 machines in a cluster anyway. What you are suggesting is the exact -opposite- of least privilege. By storing every customer's data in the same database, you are forced to grant all customers a level of access to that database. Rather than just the 20 on that cluster.